# How to reload scrollView with different array in iphone

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, nsmutablearray, uipagecontrol

I have taken 2 image arrays like

> A=["l.jpg","m.jpg","n.jpg","p.jpg","q.jpg","r.jpg"]

and

> B=["a.jpg","b.jpg","c.jpg"].

Then to display images have added scrollview with pagecontrol
(number of pages in page-control will be )

> [array count]

and also scroll-view's content size also depends on the `[array count]` i.e

> scroll.width * array.count

Here, If there are 4 pages then 3 will be loaded in memory and on scrolling previous image will be unloaded.

1) Initially displaying A array images. 
2) Then on the click of button i am replacing scrollview.contentSize , pagecontrol.numberof pages with B arrays length and also unloading images which was previously loaded by A array.
3) To display B array, scrollview contentsize will needed to be small and have number of pages as 4.So, i again reset my scrollview by

> scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(scrollView.frame.size.width *
>   [array count], scrollView.frame.size.height);

Then i scrolled upto last image in B array,after last image when i try to scroll to next image it shows as "q.jpg" image of A arrays image which was not unloaded properly.

So, how to unload all the images from scrollview when reloading from different images array.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tested, maybe you can use a for loop to set all the subview's image property to nil?

```
for(int i = 0; i < previousImageArray.count; i++)
{
   UIImageView *imageView = [[myScrollView subviews] objectAtIndex:i];

   imageView.image = nil;
}
```

If that doesn't work, you can always do a hard remove subviews:

```
// get all subviews inside your scrollview into an array
NSArray *subviews = [myScrollView subviews];

// loop through array, for each image view subview in your scrollview
// remove it from the superview (superview is your scroll view in this case)
for(int i = 0; i < subviews.count; i++)
{
    UIImageView *imageView = (UIImageView *)[subviews objectAtIndex:i];

    [imageView removeFromSuperview];
}
```

This will remove all subviews from your scrollView. You will need to re-add all the image view again when you read the new array of images.

Answer (score 0):

This is essentially what UITableViewController is for.
You can dynamically control the number and order of cells (in your case images inside custom cells) and just call reloadData on the table view when the underlying data has changed.

It also embeds the UIScrollView for you so you don't have to do the hard work.